# thrust remove copy unique by key

Tags: cuda, thrust, stream-compaction

I'm a bit confused on the best way to do the following:

Say I have the following sorted key value pairs

(K:V) (0 : .5)(0 : .7)(0 : .9) (1 : .2) (1 : .6) (1 : .8)

and so on..

I want to remove copy the minimum value of each key so I'll have 2 results

minimum by key

(0 : .5)(1 : .2)

remaining

(0 : .7)(0 : .9)(1 : .6)(1 : .8)

thrust::unique_by_key_copy would appear to be able to give me the minimum by key since (K:V) is sorted.  However I'm not sure how to remove those that are chosen from original to get the remaining.

Any thoughts or advice greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there are a number of ways to do this.

One possible approach is to use `thrust::adjacent_difference` to create a "flag array".

Then use `thrust::copy_if` (the stencil version) using the flag array (as the stencil) to select first the elements you want in result 1, then the elements you want in result 2 (using the inverse of the flag array, logically).

Here's a worked example:

```
$ cat t671.cu
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/adjacent_difference.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/zip_iterator.h>
#include <iostream>


struct is_zero
{
  __host__ __device__
  bool operator()(const int s_val) const {
    return (!s_val);}
};
struct is_not_zero
{
  __host__ __device__
  bool operator()(const int s_val) const {
    return (s_val);}
};

int main(){

  int keys[] = {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1 };
  float vals[] = {0.5f, 0.7f, 0.9f, 0.2f, 0.6f, 0.8f };
  int my_size = sizeof(keys)/sizeof(keys[0]);
  thrust::host_vector<int>     h_keys(keys, keys+my_size);
  thrust::host_vector<float>   h_vals(vals, vals+my_size);
  thrust::device_vector<int>   d_keys = h_keys;
  thrust::device_vector<float> d_vals = h_vals;
  thrust::device_vector<int>   flags(my_size);
  thrust::device_vector<int>   d_keys1(my_size);
  thrust::device_vector<float> d_vals1(my_size);
  thrust::device_vector<int>   d_keys2(my_size);
  thrust::device_vector<float> d_vals2(my_size);
  thrust::adjacent_difference(d_keys.begin(), d_keys.end(), flags.begin());
  flags[0] = 1;  // first element is always included
  int len1 = thrust::copy_if(thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(d_keys.begin(), d_vals.begin())), thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(d_keys.end(), d_vals.end())), flags.begin(), thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(d_keys1.begin(), d_vals1.begin())), is_zero()) - thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(d_keys1.begin(), d_vals1.begin()));
  int len2 = thrust::copy_if(thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(d_keys.begin(), d_vals.begin())), thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(d_keys.end(), d_vals.end())), flags.begin(), thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(d_keys2.begin(), d_vals2.begin())), is_not_zero()) - thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(d_keys2.begin(), d_vals2.begin()));

  thrust::host_vector<int>   h_keys1(len1);
  thrust::host_vector<float> h_vals1(len1);
  thrust::copy_n(d_keys1.begin(), len1, h_keys1.begin());
  thrust::copy_n(d_vals1.begin(), len1, h_vals1.begin());
  thrust::host_vector<int>   h_keys2(len2);
  thrust::host_vector<float> h_vals2(len2);
  thrust::copy_n(d_keys2.begin(), len2, h_keys2.begin());
  thrust::copy_n(d_vals2.begin(), len2, h_vals2.begin());

  std::cout << std::endl  << "Input keys:" << std::endl;
  thrust::copy(h_keys.begin(), h_keys.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl  << "Input values:" << std::endl;
  thrust::copy(h_vals.begin(), h_vals.end(), std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, ","));



  std::cout << std::endl  << "Output keys 1:" << std::endl;
  thrust::copy(h_keys1.begin(), h_keys1.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl  << "Output values 1:" << std::endl;
  thrust::copy(h_vals1.begin(), h_vals1.end(), std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl  << "Output keys 2:" << std::endl;
  thrust::copy(h_keys2.begin(), h_keys2.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl  << "Output values 2:" << std::endl;
  thrust::copy(h_vals2.begin(), h_vals2.end(), std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}

$ nvcc -arch=sm_20 -o t671 t671.cu
$ ./t671

Input keys:
0,0,0,1,1,1,
Input values:
0.5,0.7,0.9,0.2,0.6,0.8,
Output keys 1:
0,0,1,1,
Output values 1:
0.7,0.9,0.6,0.8,
Output keys 2:
0,1,
Output values 2:
0.5,0.2,
$
```